# Как разделить массив с новостями WP?

Tags: wordpress

надо вывести записи WordPress
Цель, вывести последние 4 в одном месте, остальные в другом месте. Как разделить и как получить массив

Comment: Там где будете выводить остальные укажите параметр `offset => 4`. Он добавит отступ в 4 записи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете разделить ваши посты на несколько массивов так:

```
global $wp_query;
$posts = $wp_query->posts;
// First four posts
$first_four = array_slice( $posts, 0, 4 );
foreach( $first_four as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();
}
wp_reset_postdata();

// Other posts after 4
$other_posts = array_slice( $posts, 4, count( $posts ) );
foreach( $other_posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за комментарий